# Siebel Incremental Compile - Automation Feasibility with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, command-line, siebel, incremental-compiler

I am currently working on to Automate Siebel compile through jenkins, As we all know for full compilation there is a command, however i am unable to do the same for Incremental compilation, most of the result says incremental compilation cannot be automated, is there any way? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already told you, there is absolutely NO way to do an incremental compile from the command line via Siebel Tools. If you insist on doing this, you will have to find a way to automate mouse clicks from Jenkins. I have seen some projects have automated tests on forms, using Jenkins slave, autoit and vbscripts. Theoretically, this can be used to open siebel tools, select objects and compile.

But there is lot of work involved, and the payoff might not be much.

Comment: Thank you Ranjith, We have decided to do the Incremental compile via UFT Automation Script

Answer (score 0):

Incremental compilations are not currently possible in Siebel Tools (any version) using command line switches. Incremental compile using siebdev is currently not supported.

From Siebel BookShelf v8.0: Using Siebel Tools > Compiling and Testing > Command-Line Interface for Import, Export, and Compilation, only mentions the full compile option but no partial compilation option.

Enhancement request “Ability to perform incremental compile using command line” has requested the ability to do the following:

1. Select specific project/object
2. Compile all locked projects
3. Compile all projects owned by user x

Enhancement has been closed and rejected.